# Slice Image into random sizes using C#?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, bitmap

I have been asked to come up with a way to slice an image into random sizes. Does anyone know where I would start with a project like this? I looked into the Bitmap.Clone and think this may work. I need to figure out how to get the entire image size and then randomly specify tiles of different sizes for the image size total. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something similar with a sample code to get you started:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1004794/2285597.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Start by breaking it up into different tasks:

- Make sure you can copy part of a picture
- Work out how want to split up an area into random sections. This will depend on what you want the result to look... there are all kinds of options available. (Would a simple grid be good enough? Or possibly always divide into 2 or 4 rectangles, and then recurse?)

In particular, you should be able to test each part in isolation before hooking them up to each other :)